# Find an object in "object of objects" by id value (Notion API)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an object (one record of response from Notion API), that looks like this:

```
row = {some keys here...,
 "properties": {
    "prop1": {"id": id1,
              "data": value1},
    "prop2": {"id": id2,
              "data": value2},
    "prop3": {"id": id3,
              "data": value3},
     ...

    
         }
}
```

Also I have some string `id_test`. I need to find if there's any property with `id` equeal to `id_test`, and get data from that sub-object. If there's no such an id, I need to return `null`, I guess.

Have no idea how to find and grab such a data.

Why I need this? This problem arises when I populate a Google Spreadsheet from the Notion REST API responce. Гf there were empty cells in a table, they're simply not reflected in the responce. So I first get "id"s of all the columns. Then I go to a "row" object and for each column id I have to check if there is a property with the same id. If yes, then I take the value and place it in the cell, if no - I'll leave the cell empty and move to the next id.

Comment: Look into advanced usage of `JSON.parse()` specifically its [reviver function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) on MDN. You can use that to target deeply nested properties and objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. It's pretty simple.

```
const row = {
    "properties": {
        "prop1": {
            "id": 'id1',
            "data": 'value1'
        },
        "prop2": {
            "id": 'id2',
            "data": 'value2'
        },
        "prop3": {
            "id": 'id3',
            "data": 'value3'
        }
    }
}

const findProperty = (id, props) => Object.keys(props).find(key => props[key].id === id);

const prop = findProperty('id2', row.properties);
if (prop) {
    console.log(row.properties[prop]);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. App Script executes this with expected outcome, but also reports an error: 
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Now I don't see errors, maybe misspell something

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, this is what you need to do:

```
const row = {
  properties: {
    prop1: {id: 1, data: 'apple'},
    prop2: {id: 2, data: 'samsung'},
    prop3: {id: 3, data: 'acer'},
  },
}
const id_test = '8'
let result = null
Object.keys(row.properties).map(prop => {
  if (row.properties[prop].id === Number(id_test)) {
    result = row.properties[prop].data
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this also a working solution!